# How to count the number of open editor instances in an Eclipse RCP Application?

Tags: user-interface, junit, swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I'm beginning to use the swtbot to test my reccent eclipse rcp projekt. A specific editor is opened multiple times in my application and want to count how often the editor is opened.

How can i do that using swtbot?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example of this [book on SWTBot](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/29612426/GUI-TEST-AUTOMATION-WITH-SWTBOT) (p 34), it should be

```
_bot.editors().size()
```

But that is for all the opened editors, so you may need to filter that list (based on the title of the editor for instance) to compute the right number of instances.